# Trying to populate the model before loading the View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am at a loss as I am unable to load data into the view.

We have an application that we are building as a team that handles data within the Sharepoint list.

That application is written in MVC.NET Core

That application is somehow not using the controllers and executing the post actions though a PostAsync method of a View backend (cshtml.cs)

My task is to populate the view when the view load with the data from the sharepoint list

However, when I try to assign model properties in the OnGet method or the OnGetAsync method, those properties are assigned AFTER the view loads and are not reflected on the page

I am very new at this technique

How should I load data properly into the view. Should I do through OnGet methods in the view backend?

Should I do it through a controller? If yes, how do I bind the new controller to an existing view?

No matter how much I tried, the controller I would generate wouldn't get hit with a breakpoint

What would be my appropriate action/design to populate the loading view with the data?

Thank you in advance for all your help

Here are the code samples I have so far

The View

```
@page "{ID}"
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

@model ExclusionRequestItemModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Exclusion Request Item Form";
}
@section AdditionalStyles{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/BIS232.css" asp-append-version="true" />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Exclusion Request Item Form", "DefaultController"))
{

    <div class="bisformwrapper">
        <h2>Exclusion Request Form</h2>

        <form method="post">
            <div style="width:100%; margin:0 auto;">
                <div>
                    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <h3>Product Information</h3>
                    <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-info-sign"></span>

                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                <div class="bisformdynamiclabel">Product Type</div>
                                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" asp-for="BIS232Request.Title" />
                                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" asp-for="BIS232Request.Status" />
                                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" asp-for="BIS232Request.Product" />
                                <div id="MetalType">
                            <div class="bisformdynamiclabel" id="MetalClass">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.BIS232Request.Product)</div>
```

```
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <br />

                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
}
```

The view backend (.cs)

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using BIS232WebProject.Model;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
using BIS232WebProject.Controllers;

namespace BIS232WebProject.Pages.Forms
{
    public class ExclusionRequestItemModel : PageModel
    {
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnGet(int ID)
        {
            ItemID = ID;



            JToken jsonData = null;
            Task<string> outerTask = GetExclusionRequestJSON(ID.ToString());
            outerTask.ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                string result = task.Result;

                var jobj = JObject.Parse(result);
                jsonData = jobj["fields"];

                if (jsonData != null)
                {
                    var jobjFields = JObject.Parse(jsonData.ToString());
                    var JSONData = jobjFields["JSONData"];

                    if (JSONData != null)
                    {
                        var JSONDataFields = JObject.Parse(JSONData.ToString());
                        BIS232Request.Product = JSONDataFields["Product"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                        BIS232Request.JSONData.MetalClass = JSONDataFields["MetalClass"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;
                    }
                }

            });

            var requestVm = new ExclusionRequestItemModel();

            requestVm.BIS232Request.JSONData.MetalClass = "This was set in the model before rendering the view and should be overwritten.";

            return Page();


            //return Page(requestVm);

        }

        //private readonly BIS232Request.JSONData.MetalClas _context;

        //public CreateModel(BIS232WebProject.Models.RazorPagesMovieContext context)
        //{
        //    _context = context;
        //}

        public static async Task<string> GetExclusionRequestJSON(string ID)
        {
            var status = string.Empty;
            try
            {

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var content = new StringContent("{ID:1}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    //var result = client.GetAsync("https://itasharepointapi.azurewebsites.net/api/GetAllExclusionRequests").Result.Content;
                    //https://itasharepointapi.azurewebsites.net/api/GetAllExclusionRequests

                    string requestUrl = "https://itasharepointapi.azurewebsites.net/api/GetExclusionRequestById";
                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), requestUrl);

                    request.Content = new StringContent("{\"ID\":1}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);


                    string jsonContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                    return jsonContent;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                status = $"Error updating the Sharepoint list: {ex.Message}";
            }

            return status;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public ExclusionRequest BIS232Request { get; set; } = new ExclusionRequest()
        {

            Product = "Steel",
            Status = "New Request",
            Title = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            JSONData = new MetalExclusionData()
            {
                Ports = new List<string>() { "" },
                ProductStandards = new List<ProductStandard>() { new ProductStandard() { Organization = "Please Select", Designation = "" } },
                MetalClass = "vasua"
            }
            //HTSUSCode = "1234"
            //,OwnershipActivity = new OwnershipActivity(){
            //    Ownership =""
            //}
        };

        //public async Task OnGetAsync()
        //{
        //    //Customers = await _db.Customers.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        //    string vasya = "";
        //}

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(ExclusionRequest bIS232Request)
        {
            if (bIS232Request.JSONData.OwnershipActivity == null || bIS232Request.JSONData.OwnershipActivity.Ownership == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("OwnershipAnswer", "You must select an option.");
            }
            if (bIS232Request.JSONData.ExclusionRequesterActivity == null || bIS232Request.JSONData.ExclusionRequesterActivity == "" || bIS232Request.JSONData.ExclusionRequesterActivity == "Please Select")
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("ExclusionRequesterActivity", "You must select an option.");
            }
            if (bIS232Request.JSONData.ExclusionRequesterActivity == "Other" && bIS232Request.JSONData.ExclusionRequesterComments == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("ExclusionRequesterActivityComment", "Please provide comments.");
            }
            if (bIS232Request.JSONData.ExclusionExplanation.Explanation == "Other" && bIS232Request.JSONData.ExclusionExplanation.Comments == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("ExclusionExplanationAnswer", "Please provide comments.");
            }
            //ExclusionExplanationAnswer


            if (bIS232Request.JSONData.NonUSProducer == null || bIS232Request.JSONData.NonUSProducer.BehalfOf == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("BehalfOfAnswer", "You must select an option.");
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            //Do POST to database then redirect to Index
            //string bIS232RequestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bIS232Request);
            //string status = await InsertModelIntoSharepointList(bIS232RequestJson);

            //set JSONData section from parent object
            BIS232Request.JSONData.Status = BIS232Request.Status;
            BIS232Request.JSONData.HTSUSCode = BIS232Request.HTSUSCode;
            BIS232Request.JSONData.Product = BIS232Request.Product;
            return Page();
            //return RedirectToPage("../Index");
        }


    }
}
```

The Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BIS232WebProject.Model
{
    public class ExclusionRequest
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Product { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Comment: I would recommend sharing some code that you need assistance on. Show what you did so far.

Comment: Aleksandr thank you for your feedback

I did put in as much code as I could

Comment: Please don't put as much code as you can, this is nearly as bad as adding no code at all. Please create a [**MINIMAL**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. *Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem*

Comment: Liam, I shortened the code

Trying to display a Product string but it doesn't comes through. Instead it display a class name

Please let me know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your patience and understanding. I got my answers and now I am ready to proceed

1. I was able to populate the Model properties in the OnGetAsync method
2. I was able to display the data using the DisplayFor syntax